# Visual Studio 2015 Extensions Manager Index was out of range error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Env: Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on Windows 8

Trying to open Tools --> Extensions and Updates results in the following error in a message box:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Parameter name: index
```

Tried running as Admin, same result.

I've tried [looking at the log](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-extensions-with-the-activity-log/) but nothing mentions that error.

In the log there are 3 error entries related to extensions which could be related, they say the following:

`Error loading extension: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\path\to\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0\EXTENSIONS\ZW2UF5JV.JVN\extension.vsixmanifest'.`

The other 2 are identical except the odd string at the end is `HQ1Y5EQD.TMG` and `3KWE1LJF.Z1W`.

Interestingly, just before those errors in the log appear, there is a line for each saying the extension was loaded successfully but if I try to go to the path it's got listed, it doesn't exist.

I can't find any reference to those strings on my machine. I've also searched the registry but can't find any reference in there either.

I can get into the Extensions manager if I click on one of the update notifications but the original error message just displays in the main pane and I can't do anything else. I can get to the online window but as soon as I click an extension, I am prompted with the original message.

I haven't installed any extensions or VS updates for a while but my [Web Compiler extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c) extension has stopped auto compiling JSX files which is why I started trying to look at the Extension manager. I'm guessing the issues are related.

I can still work, compiling can be done manually which is inconvenient but not the end of the world. My worry is some other extensions are also misbehaving and I just haven't noticed yet.

Don't really want to re-install VS as a) it took ages last time and b) it might not fix the issue. Is there any good advice on troubleshooting the error or anything else I can try before I re-install?

Comment: I'd try to either reload/repair VS2015, or go to the extensions directory and delete everything there.  It seems as if VS thinks there are VSIX extnsions to load but they're not there... I also think there's a bug in VS because index out of range implies that it doesn't know what to do if nothing is found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem got worse, I started getting the error message when starting Visual Studio and things like the package manager wouldn't load. Each restart seemed to yield a different combination of windows not loading, sometimes Solution Explorer, sometimes Team Explorer etc. Not good.

A repair to VS 2015 via the Control Panel took a while but didn't help, same problems.

I ended up completely uninstalling and trying to re-install. However the installer threw an index was out of range error but weirdly VS 2015 was now listed as an installed application again.

So I'm guessing the original uninstall left some problematic files lying around which messed up the next install. So I uninstalled again, renamed Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 folder, cleared all files from `AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions` and re-installed.

It installed and ran fine.

The problem I now had was that I couldn't find the SQL Server Object Explorer window anywhere. I tried repairing SQL Server Data Tools but still no luck. So I uninstalled SSDT and then re-installed. This seemed to fix it.

Now I realised I also couldn't connect to Azure through the Server Explorer window, the option was simply not appearing in the list like it used to. This time a repair to `Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9` and a repair to `Azure App Service Tools v2.9 - Visual Studio 2015` fixed that problem.

Comment: "cleared all files from AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions" 
Just do this will do. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I refreshed the GitHub extension on VS 2015 and got this error. Deleting the two cache files:

extensions.en-US.cache
  extensionSdks.en-US.cache

from the AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions causes them to be rebuilt and eliminates the error.

No reinstall needed.

Answer (score 0):

I confronted same issue and found this thread. I tried the above suggestions, but unfortunately, it went all unsuccessful. I even tried to uninstall/install with even worse result as Visual Studio became unable to start due to new "**missing components**" issue. Reinstallation was nothing better.

I finally came by a piece of magic. It was [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) which although would remove all your installed extensions, it would perform a complete cleanup. It would save you from installing new Windows (at least it was my case.

Just go to [releases](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases) and download the first zip file

[image]

[image]

This way you will be able to perform clean install of Visual Studio.